# Convert HTML to Pandas DF keeping Rows based on Class

Tags: python, html, pandas

Interesting problem here. I typically use `pd.read_html` to convert nice HTML tables into dataframes, cleaning the data afterwards. This is the first time where the data I get actually *needs* to be cleaned at the HTML level. Specifically, I need to only keep the header row (the `<th>` row) and all rows with a certain `class` before converting into a df. So I suppose I am looking for a solution that allows me to pre-select certain HTML rows while keeping a format that `pd.read_html` accepts, or pre-select certain HTML rows and then converting to a df without using `pd.read_html`.

The full table HTML is pretty long, so I included a simple example of the HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>head item 1</th><th>head item 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="class_1"><td>item1</td><td>item2</td></tr>
    <tr class="class_2"><td>item1</td><td>item2</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So In the above example I would want the header and all of the rows with `class_1`...and then a way to still put that into a df cleanly. Thanks for any help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cleaning the HTML data, you can use the Beautiful Soup library.

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Create a variable out of your html table and pass it to BS. Then, you can use BS methods like findAll to filter the data for what you need. I've added some additional rows of data to your example to illustrate.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>head item 1</th><th>head item 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="class_1"><td>item1</td><td>item2</td></tr>
    <tr class="class_1"><td>item3</td><td>item4</td></tr>
    <tr class="class_1"><td>item5</td><td>item6</td></tr>
    <tr class="class_2"><td>item1</td><td>item2</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
'''

# Filter the html table using BS
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
header_soup = soup.findAll('th')
row_soup = soup.findAll('tr', attrs={"class": "class_1"})

# Select header text and turn it into a list for Pandas
headers = []
for h in header_soup:
  headers.append(h.text)

# Select row cell text and turn it into a list for Pandas
rows = []
for row in row_soup:
  row_data = []
  for cell in row.findAll('td'):
    row_data.append(cell.text)
  rows.append(row_data)

# Create the dataframe from your table data
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers)
```